Custom Session Provider GetItem not get called when accessing data from Session
I am trying to wirite a custom session provider in .net framework 4.8. What I do not understand, and my problem is that when I try to access data like
Session[key] I imagine that the session provider GetItem should got called, but that's not happening.
Here is my session provider prototype where I was trying to do this:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace MVC
{
    public class PPMSesseionStateProvider : SessionStateStoreProviderBase
    {
        private string baseURl = string.Empty;

        public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["description"]))
            {
                config.Remove("description");
                config.Add("description", "Custom PPM Session State Store provider");
            }

            baseURl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseURL"];

            base.Initialize(name, config);
        }

        public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(HttpContext context, int timeout)
        {
            return new SessionStateStoreData(new SessionStateItemCollection(), SessionStateUtility.GetSessionStaticObjects(context), timeout);
        }

        public override void CreateUninitializedItem(HttpContext context, string id, int timeout)
        {}

        public override void Dispose()
        {}

        public override void EndRequest(HttpContext context)
        {}

        public override SessionStateStoreData GetItem(HttpContext context, string id, out bool locked, out TimeSpan lockAge, out object lockId, out SessionStateActions actions)
        {
            //SAME AS GETITEM
            var request = WebRequest.Create($"https://localhost:5000/SessionTest/get/asdfrgfds");
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("PPMSessionHeader", "12345");
            var sessionResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


            // Initial values for return value and out parameters.
            SessionStateStoreData item = null;
            lockAge = TimeSpan.Zero;
            lockId = null;
            locked = false;
            actions = 0;

            var response = string.Empty; //get the reposnse form the server (look for the object type in the server) and create

            SessionStateItemCollection sessionItems = new SessionStateItemCollection();

            if (sessionResponse.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var reader = new BinaryReader(sessionResponse.GetResponseStream());
                sessionItems = SessionStateItemCollection.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            return new SessionStateStoreData(sessionItems, SessionStateUtility.GetSessionStaticObjects(context), 1000);
        }

        public override SessionStateStoreData GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, string id, out bool locked, out TimeSpan lockAge, out object lockId, out SessionStateActions actions)
        {
            //SAME AS GETITEM
            var request = WebRequest.Create($"https://localhost:5000/SessionTest/get/asdfrgfds");
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("PPMSessionHeader", "12345");
            var sessionResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


            // Initial values for return value and out parameters.
            SessionStateStoreData item = null;
            lockAge = TimeSpan.Zero;
            lockId = null;
            locked = false;
            actions = 0;

            var response = string.Empty; //get the reposnse form the server (look for the object type in the server) and create

            SessionStateItemCollection sessionItems = new SessionStateItemCollection();

            if (sessionResponse.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var reader = new BinaryReader(sessionResponse.GetResponseStream());
                sessionItems = SessionStateItemCollection.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            return new SessionStateStoreData(sessionItems, SessionStateUtility.GetSessionStaticObjects(context), 1000);
        }

        public override void InitializeRequest(HttpContext context)
        {}

        public override void ReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, string id, object lockId)
        {}

        public override void RemoveItem(HttpContext context, string id, object lockId, SessionStateStoreData item)
        {
           //send request to remove item from session
        }

        public override void ResetItemTimeout(HttpContext context, string id)
        {}

        public override void SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, string id, SessionStateStoreData item, object lockId, bool newItem)
        {
            //send the key and the value to the API
        }

        public override bool SetItemExpireCallback(SessionStateItemExpireCallback expireCallback) => false;
    }
}

The controller action where I test this:
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string key = "ProductID:1001";
    var customObject = Session[key]; // at this line nothing is triggered !!!
    Session.Add(key, "tralalalala");


    return View();
}

thnx

Any particular reason why you are using a Custom Session handler?

Yes, 2 app, one is .net core (API) and the session lives there now, and and the second is .net framework (MVC), and I need the session in the MVC that lives in the API

Not sure why you have implemented Session in the API project. The entire point of API is to be stateless. In your MVC application, have you tried using the inbuilt session technique: https://www.bytehide.com/blog/session-in-mvc#:~:text=Session%20state%20is%20a%20built,session%20data%20throughout%20your%20application.

Do not ask the reason, was not my decision.

Ok, so now you are trying to implement what is done in the API project in your MVC project. In MVC, you have Session implementation done by the framework. Have you tried looking into that?
